# A set of vectors which span $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

That's a question from Hoffman and Kunze book Linear Algebra.

This system can be represented by the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & \frac{4}{3} & -1 & 0\\\ 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & -1\\\ 9 & -3 & 6 & -3 & -3\end{pmatrix}$

Row-reducing it we get:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -2\\\ 
1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & -1\\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Thus the system is equivalent to

$\begin{cases}
x_2 + x_4 -2x_5 = 0\\\ 
x_1 + \frac{2}{3}x_3-x_5 = 0
\end{cases}$

A vector $\alpha$ of $W$ satisfies this condition, and so has the form
$\alpha = (x_5-\frac{2}{3}x_3,2x_5-x_4,x_3,x_4,x_5)$

Thus

$\alpha = x_3(-\frac{2}{3},0,1,0,0) + x_4(0,-1,0,1,0)+ x_5(1,2,0,0,1)$

From this $W$ is the subspace spanned by the set $S$ of vectors $S = (-\frac{2}{3},0,1,0,0), (0,-1,0,1,0), (1,2,0,0,1)$.

Is this solution valid ?

Comment: This look fine and the dimension match. Look that you are working in $\mathbb{R}^5$ and have $2$ equations, so the dimension of $W$ has to be at least $3$.